# Ошибка при конкатенации строк

Tags: c, массивы, строки, консоль

Не понимаю в чем дело. Создал структуру, при заполнении один из параметров должен получаться путем сложения строк.

Код:

```
struct items
{
    const char *name;
    const char *mark;
    float value;
    const char *namemark;

} ; 

void print(items a)
{
    printf("name = %s, mark = %s, value = %f\n", a.name, a.mark, a.value);
    printf("----");
    printf("name/mark = %s",a.namemark);
}

int main()
{
   struct items a[2];
   a[0].name =  "board";
   a[1].name =  "bucicle";
   a[0].mark = "stels";
   a[1].mark = "stern";
   a[0].value = 200;
   a[1].value = 150;
   a[0].namemark = strcat (a[0].name, a[0].mark);
   a[1].namemark = strcat (a[1].name, a[1].mark);

   for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        print(a[i]);
   }
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Опустил `a[0]` для краткости...

```
namemark = strcat (name, mark);
```

Означает: к строке в массиве символов, на который указывает `name`, дописать строку, хранящуюся в массиве символов, на который указывает `mark`, и присвоить указатель на массив `name` указателю `namemark`.

У вас нет выделенных массивов, вы просто присваиваете `name` указатель на строку в памяти; `strcat` будет пытаться писать за ней, залазя в чужую память и портя ее.

Вы должны выделить память для строк с помощью, скажем `malloc`, а потом заполнить ее. Что-то типа

```
name = malloc(10);
mark = malloc(10);
namemark = malloc(20);
strcpy(name,"board");
strcpy(mark,"stels");
strcpy(namemark,name);
strcat(namemark,mark);
```

Comment: Понял...) но все равно при попытке выделить память, вылезает ошибка...(

Comment: код:struct items a[2];
    a[0].mark = malloc(20);
    a[0].name = malloc(20);
    a[0].namemark = malloc(20);
    a[0].value = malloc(20);
    a[1].mark = malloc(20);
    a[1].name = malloc(20);
    a[1].namemark = malloc(20);
    a[1].value = malloc(20);

Comment: ошибка: Error 2 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'const char *'